# Attaching files using plain TeX (pdfTeX)

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, attachfile, embedfile

I am currently in the process of writing a document using plain TeX and would like to be able to attach other relevant files to the resulting pdf. I have experience using the attachfile, attachfile2 and embedfile packages (successfully) for this purpose (in LaTeX) in the past.

Whilst I could revert to using LaTeX, I would prefer to define a suitable macro for use in plain TeX. I have read the relevant sections of the pdf specification as well as the pdfTeX user manual however I have not yet been able to create a macro which makes this possible.

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts and/or assistance.

---

**Edit 1: Reference Documents**

Please find below links to relevant reference documents:

- Adobe PDF reference document (currently available from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html
- pdfTeX user manual (currently available from http://ctan.org/pkg/pdftex
- attachfile2 package documentation (currently available from http://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2. For a successful implementation reference (pdfLaTeX).
- embedfile package documentation (currently available from http://www.ctan.org/pkg/embedfile

---

**Edit 2: Current Solution Approach**

System Information:

- Fedora 20
- pdfTeX 3.1415926

Please find below the code for a minimal working example as well as my current approach which uses only plain TeX and pdfTeX primitives.

---

**File:** alphabet.txt

*This is the file that is to be attached to the document*.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

---

**File:** minimal.tex

*This file makes use of the attachfile2 package to demonstrate how this can be achieved using LaTeX (pdfLaTeX).*

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{attachfile2}
\begin{document}

    Hello, world!

    \textattachfile{alphabet.txt}{some annotation}

\end{document}
```

---

**File:** test.tex

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\catcode`@=11
\def\res@space{ }

\newcount\res@count@obj@file
\newcount\res@count@obj@xform
\newcount\res@count@obj@fspec

\newdimen\res@box@dp
\newdimen\res@box@ht
\newdimen\res@box@wd

\def\res@embefile#1{%
    \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{%
        /Type /EmbeddedFile
        /Params <<
            /Size \pdffilesize{#1}
            /ModDate (\pdffilemoddate{#1})
            /CheckSum <\pdfmdfivesum file {#1}>
        >>
    } file {#1}
    \res@count@obj@file=\the\pdflastobj
}

\def\res@appearance@box#1{%
    \setbox1=\hbox{#1}
    \immediate\pdfxform 1
    \res@count@obj@xform=\the\pdflastxform
    \res@box@dp=\the\dp1
    \res@box@ht=\the\ht1
    \res@box@wd=\the\wd1
}

\def\res@filespec#1{%
    \immediate\pdfobj{
        <<
            /Type /Filespec
            /FS (#1)
            /EF <<
                /F \the\res@count@obj@file\res@space 0 R
            >>
         >>
    }
    \res@count@obj@fspec=\the\pdflastobj
}

\def\res@annot{
    \pdfannot   width \the\res@box@wd
                height \the\res@box@ht
                depth \the\res@box@dp {
        /Subtype /FileAttachment
        /AP <<
            /N \the\res@count@obj@xform\res@space 0 R
            /R \the\res@count@obj@xform\res@space 0 R
            /D \the\res@count@obj@xform\res@space 0 R
        >>
        /F \the\res@count@obj@file
        /FS \the\res@count@obj@fspec\res@space 0 R
    }
}

\def\res@attachfile#1#2{%    Arg 1:  Annotation
                        %    Arg 2:  Name of file to be attached
    \res@embedfile{#2}
    \res@filespec{#2}
    \res@appearance@box{#1}
    \res@annot
}

Hello, world!

\res@attachfile{some annotation}{alphabet.txt}

\bye
```

---

Provided that *alphabet.txt* is stored in the same directory, the desired output can be produced by running:

```
pdflatex minimal.tex
```

My current approach is capable of producing a *.pdf* file which is viewable using Document Viewer (I have not yet checked whether it is capable of being opened by Adobe Reader). The *.pdf* can be produced by running:

```
pdftex test.tex
```

By comparing the output between the two approaches, it appears that the attachment is being embedded correctly. I am not however, able to 'see' the annotation on the pdf and I am unable to open the attachment.

It would be much appreciated if someone could identify the error for me.

Comment: Oh! It is very nice that you are thinking of plain TeX equivalents of LaTeX constructions! Difficult, but very interesting. And BTW [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)

Comment: When you say you'd rather define suitable macros for use in plain TeX, do you mean that you explicitly wish to circumvent the `miniltx.tex` macros?

Comment: @1010011010 Thank you for making me aware of the `miniltx.tex` macros. It would be my preference to avoid using the miniltx.tex macros in order to avoid introducing dependencies. The purpose of that package appears to be introducing a minimal set of macros to plain TeX in order to make it possible to include LaTeX files directly. Please correct me if I am wrong as I only briefly looked at the file.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Thank you for your welcome!

Comment: I just did a quick test using ChrisS's answer and now I wonder: how do you view such an embedded file? I tried Evince and Adobe Reader, but to no avail.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel In Adobe Reader, you can view the attachments using the Attachments Pane, which is opened using the paperclip icon on the left side of the window. If this icon is not visible, you can show it using View > Show/Hide > Navigation Panes > Attachments.

Comment: @ChrisS Hmm, I `XeTeX`'ed a file with `\embeddedfile[foo]{bar}[baz]{alphabet.txt}` in it (after `\finishpdffile`, of course), but I don't see an attachment in Adobe Reader (9.5.5). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I used a MWE of `\input navigator \embeddedfile[foo]{bar}[baz]{159.txt} ABC \finishpdffile \bye` with XeTeX and [it works for me](http://imgur.com/jRymS1Q) in Acrobat Pro.

Comment: @ChrisS Ah, you should embed the file *before* `\finishpdffile`, that was not clear from your answer.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I'm very curious if you have found the solution. See my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284634/how-to-attach-files-in-luatex-in-pdf-mode

Comment: something is wrong with your `test.tex`: when I compile it and try to open the resulting pdf document, my pdf viewer crashes with `segmentation fault` message

Comment: Why not simply add the PDF file *outside* of \TeX using e.g. PdfShuffler. You can use it to place the desire PDF file within what \Tex has created (suggestion uses XeTex, instead of PDFtex)

Answer (score 6):

The [`navigator`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/navigator) package allows access to links, attachments and other PDF features in Plain TeX, LaTeX and ConteXt. If you add

```
\input navigator
```

to your preamble and

```
\finishpdffile
```

to the end of your document, you can attach a file to your document with

```
\embeddedfile[<description>]{<object name>}[<alternate file name>]{<file>}
```

where `<description>` is the description listed in the PDF viewer, `<object name>` is the internal name of the attachment, `<alternate file name>` is the file name listed in the PDF viewer and `<file>` is, of course, the file you want to attach.