# How to attach files in LuaTeX in pdf mode?

Tags: pdf, luatex, plain-tex, dvipdfmx

I have this code to attach files via dvipdfmx, and it works well:

```
\def\attach#1{%
  \special{pdf:fstream @file (#1)}%
  \special{pdf:ann bbox 0 0 10 10
  <</Type /Annot /Subtype /FileAttachment
  /FS <</Type /Filespec /F (#1.txt)
  /EF <</F @file>> >> /Name /PushPin>>}}
\attach{\jobname.tex}
\bye
```

If I use `navigator` package, I don't see the button to open the file:

```
\pdfoutput=1
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\input navigator
\embeddedfile{sourcecode}{test.tex}
A
\bye
```

This topic is relevant, but I could not make these examples to work in LuaTeX: [Attaching files using plain TeX (pdfTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208012/attaching-files-using-plain-tex-pdftex)

How should the above dvipdfmx code be changed to work with luatex in pdf mode?

Comment: See packages `attachfile`, `attachfile2`, `embedfile`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Yes, I saw them, but it seems to me that all of them work only in LaTeX (not plain luatex). And I could not peel the solution from these packages to make it as simple as possible (like in dvipdfmx example).

Comment: Package `embedfile` also works with plain TeX. Also these packages contain the low level code for driver pdfTeX, which also can be used for LuaTeX.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I tried `embedfile-example-plain.tex` from `texlive-latex-base-doc` package. It requires to use miniltx. This is not what is needed. Can it work without miniltx? Also, I did not see the button to open the attachment, whereas in my dvipdfmx example such button appears in the document.

Comment: Package `embedfile` can be even be used without `plain.tex` with iniTeX. There is no dependency on `miniltx.tex`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: `embedfile` does not allow to open attachments with a button click. This is not what is needed. Is it possible to make the same output document as in the `dvipdfmx` example?

Comment: Package `embedfile` includes the file at a document basis. The `attachfile` packages use annotations on pages instead. However, the latter packages are using LaTeX. But the low level primitives can be studied in the driver files, e.g. `atfi-pdftex.def`. Should not be too hard for a plain TeX hardcore user.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I found the solution, but not fully understand the details. See **EDIT**

Comment: Replace `(#1.txt)` by `(\pdfescapestring{#1.txt})`.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works as required:

```
\pdfoutput=1
\def\attach#1{%
  \immediate\pdfobj stream file {#1}%
  \pdfannot width 10pt height 10pt depth 0pt {
    /Subtype /FileAttachment
    /C [ 0 0.5 0 ]
    /FS << /F (#1.txt)
    /Type /Filespec
    /EF << /F \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R >> >>}}
\attach{\jobname.tex}
\bye
```